# Non-static method App\Helper\WebHelpers::GetCategories() cannot be called statically got error in blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i got this error in laravel
Error
Non-static method App\Helper\WebHelpers::GetCategories() cannot be called statically

code is mention below

```
            <div class="form-group">

                <label>Categories</label>

                <select name="filter_category" id="filter_category" class="form-control custom-select" style="height: 44px !important;border: 1px solid #f2f2f2 !important;" id="cty">

                    <option value="">All</option>

                    @foreach (App\Helper\WebHelpers::GetCategories('event-categories') as $item)

                        <option value="{{$item->id}}" @isset($filter_city) @if($item->id == $filter_city) selected @endif @endisset>{{$item->category}}</option>

                    @endforeach

                </select>

            </div>
```

why i got this error

Comment: Show us the `WebHelpers` class, ideally the error seems to tell us that the method you're calling is not static.

Comment: seems quite self-explanatory ... is there a reason you are expecting something different to be happening?

Comment: In your helper add static keyword to GetCategories method so you can access it using "::"

Comment: Share GetCategories method code